# How to format currency in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm beginner in JavaScript and I'm rendering a list that contains some products.

The product price format comes as follows: `3800`, `4000`, `11000`, etc.

The way I should show the user is: `38.00`, `40.00`, `110.00`, etc.

But when I use `Intl.NumberFormat`, the value is in the format: `3.800,00 €`, etc.

Can you tell me how to use `Intl.NumberFormat` correctly to leave the values in the correct format?

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/format-currency-gx8ux?file=/src/App.js)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So it's in cents instead of euros? Just divide by 100 and then format it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format numbers as currency string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-string)

Comment: Format of string returned by `Intl.NumberFormat` depends on your local settings.

Comment: Hey James, I divided the amount by 100, but it was 38.00 and not 38.00. Do you know how I can change the comma for the period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let num = 3400/100;
console.log(num.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}));
```

will output > 34.00

I notice in your code that you are using **'de-DE'** that will always format the currency to use comas `,` as the decimal marker, if you change your code to use **'en-IN'** will use dot `.` as the decimal marker.

You can read all about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: `if you change your code to use 'en-IN'` good as a hack, but not a solution. May cause some problems in the future.

Answer (score -1):

divide the price by 100 and if you want the last two decimal point like `38.00` try this `let price = (3800/100).toFixed(2)`

Comment: Hey Dipankar, I didn't give the downvote. I divided the amount by 100, but it was 38.00 and not 38.00. Do you know how I can change the comma for the period?

Comment: You can have a workaround like this ```let value="88,9827"; let newValue=value.replace(",", "."); console.log(newValue); ```

Comment: @ArtuX the author needs help on formating the output of the Intl.NumberFormat method not on how to convert the number